# Unable to connect to a virtual machine docker container's port after reverting to latest snapshot with memory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtual-machine

I have a CentOS 7 virtual machine (let's call it A) that has a docker container running on it. Here's what I see when running `docker ps`

```
253080832d45   gitlab/gitlab-ce:15.11.5-ce.0                                    "/assets/wrapper"         7 days ago     Up 7 days (healthy)   443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10023->22/tcp, :::10023->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10081->80/tcp, :::10081->80/tcp   gitlab-ce-web-1
```

As you can see from above, it has port 10081 opened.

I have another CentOS 7 virtual machine called B. I'd like to know why I can't connect to A's 10081 port from B after I revert A to its latest snapshot with memory.

[image]

Here's part of the information of `iptables --list` of A:

```
Chain DOCKER (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:commplex-main
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.2           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.2           tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.21.0.2           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.21.0.2           tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.22.0.4           tcp dpt:webcache

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

And here's what I see inside the docker container in A.

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:15:00:02
          inet addr:172.21.0.2  Bcast:172.21.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9246 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7487 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1889900 (1.8 MiB)  TX bytes:5311730 (5.0 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1712543 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1712543 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:14194815387 (13.2 GiB)  TX bytes:14194815387 (13.2 GiB)
```

And here's what I see inside host machine A.

```
$ firewall-cmd --list-all
FirewallD is not running

$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Do you know why I can't connect to A's 10081 port from B?

If you need any other information, please let me know. I'll provide as much information as I can.

I found that after running `systemctl restart docker` in A, I can connect to A's 10081 port from B. But I still want to know why I can't cannect to A before running `systemctl restart docker`.